# Modifying module level variables in an anonymous array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dictionary

I am in the midst of learning Ruby and thought I was clever with the following piece of code:

```
[@start,@end].map!{ |time| time += operation == :add ? amount : -(amount) }
```

where @start, @end are two module level variables, operation can be one of :add or :sub, and amount is an float amount to adjust both @start and @end by.

Granted it only saves me a line of code, but why doesn't this approach work, and how can I get something similar that does?

(My expected output is for @start/@end to be modified accordingly, however unit tests show that they stay at their original values.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important in Ruby to remember the distinction between variables and the objects they hold. Simply setting a variable will never change the object referenced by that variable. When you do `a += b`, it's just shorthand for `a = a + b`. So you're assigning a new value to the variable a, not changing the object that used to be there or changing any other references to that object. So changing the variable `time` doesn't change `@start`.

In order to assign to an instance variable, you need to actually assign to that instance variable. Here's a way to do what you were looking for:

```
operation = :+
amount = 12
@start, @end = [@start, @end].map {|time| time.send(operation, amount)}
```

You'll notice that we're not faffing around with that `:add` and `:sub` business either — we can just pass the actual name of the message we want to send (I used + in this case, but it could be anything).

If you had a big, dynamically generated list of ivars you wanted to set, it's only a little bit more complicated. The only difference there is that need to get and set the ivars by name.

```
ivars = [:@start, :@end, :@something_else]
operation = :+
amount = 12
ivars.each {|ivar| instance_variable_set(ivar, instance_variable_get(ivar).send(operation, amount))}
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Shows how much my C# assumptions just do not apply in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

The `+=` operator changes the value of `time` but it returns the old value of `time`, therefore the right code is:

```
@start,@end = [@start,@end].map!{ |time| time + (operation == :add ? amount : -amount) }
```

**EDIT**
Updated the code to actually change `@start` and `@end`.

Comment: Hmm still no dice.  @start += operation == :add ? amount : -(amount) is working, but not when I try to do it through Array#map block. :(

Comment: Yup this works, thanks!  (I'm picking Chuck's answer because he's done a good job of explaining what's happening under the hood, and how I can think alternatively about Ruby.)

Answer (score 2):

The addition operation in the block doesn't modify 'time', it returns a new value. So the elements in the array aren't modified, they're replaced.

Comment: This makes sense.  I guess there's no way to get my code to work as I want to write it.